# Convert list of lists variable to multiple variables in data frame

Tags: r

I am scraping a website API and I'm having issues converting their variables that come in the form of list of lists into columns in my data frame.

The final variable in my data frame is a variable that has many lists within it. How can I expand these to all be variables in the higher level data frame?

My ideal output would be a data frame with the following columns:

`id`, `date`, `patch`, `tournament`, `stage`, `round`, `series`, `game`, `map`, `url`, `team`, `is_winner`, `bans`, etc.

My last column (`df$drafts`) contains a lot of data that I want. I don't know how to get it out of the list of lists.

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you need any clarification!

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://api.masterleague.net/matches"
data <- GET(url)
data <- content(data)
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(data[[4]],c)))
```

If you would rather just work with an example row of `df`, here is the output:

```
df <- structure(list(id = list(2394L), date = list("2017-03-05"), patch = list(18L), tournament = list(38L), stage = list(175L), round = list(
    "Grand Final"), series = list(850L), game = list(5L), map = list(6L), url = list("https://masterleague.net/match/2394/"), drafts = list(list(structure(list(team = 20L, is_winner = TRUE, bans = list(53L, 30L), picks = list(structure(list(hero = 50L,player = 438L), .Names = c("hero", "player")), structure(list( hero = 26L, player = 102L), .Names = c("hero", "player" )), structure(list(hero = 52L, player = 104L), .Names = c("hero",  "player")), structure(list(hero = 23L, player = 103L), .Names = c("hero",   "player")), structure(list(hero = 34L, player = 101L), .Names = c("hero",  "player")))), .Names = c("team", "is_winner", "bans", "picks")), structure(list(team = 21L, is_winner = FALSE,  bans = list(51L, 35L), picks = list(structure(list(hero = 32L,   player = 107L), .Names = c("hero", "player")), structure(list( hero = 47L, player = 108L), .Names = c("hero", "player" )), structure(list(hero = 21L, player = 106L), .Names = c("hero",  "player")), structure(list(hero = 48L, player = 110L), .Names = c("hero",  "player")), structure(list(hero = 20L, player = 105L), .Names = c("hero",  "player")))), .Names = c("team", "is_winner", "bans",  "picks"))))), .Names = c("id", "date", "patch", "tournament",  "stage", "round", "series", "game", "map", "url", "drafts"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

I have unsuccessfully tried using `rbind.data.frame`, `do.call(rbind)`, `sapply`, and other methods that I found here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
# use lapply to make a list of the unlisted lists (try saying that 10 times fast)
# within your last column
drafts <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) unlist(df$drafts[i]))

# collapse that list into a data frame with rows corresponding to the ones in df
drafts2 <- do.call(rbind, drafts)

# use cbind to append that new data frame to the original one
df2 <- cbind(df, drafts2)
```

Or, if you want to do it in one shot:

```
cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) unlist(df$drafts[i]))))
```